# Parse.com Storing multiple ParseObjects at the same time

Tags: parse-platform

The documentation for the Parse SDK talks about how to store an individual ParseObject, however it doesn't mention if you can store multiple Parse Objects at the same time. I've tried searching on it, but have found nothing relevant.

I was just wondering if anyone knows of a way of doing this, or is the only method to call the save method on each parse object that you wish to save?

Answer (score 0):

You start by declaring a list of parseObjects,
it goes like this ....

```
List<ParseObject> listObjects = new ArrayList<ParseObject>(); 
  listObjects.add( new ParseObject("key_name") );
  listObjects.add( new ParseObject("key_name") );
  listObjects.add( new ParseObject("key_name") );
  listObjects.add( new ParseObject("key_name") );
```

then call the static method of ParseObject with parameters(list and callback)

```
ParseObject.saveAllInBackground( listObjects ,new SaveCallback() {
 @Override
 public void done(ParseException e){
     if(e != null){
     //success
     }
 }

}
```